# Loading font in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is My CSS Code

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'vanavil Avvaiyar';
src: url('../fonts/vanavil Avvaiyar.TTF') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Bamini';
src: url('../fonts/Bamini.TTF') format('truetype');
}
```

I want to use the above two fonts based on a dropdown selection.

This is my Controller

```
$scope.fonts = [
    {
        "fontName": "Bamini"
    },
    {
        "fontName": "vanavil Avvaiyar"
    }
]
```

This is my HTML Drop Down

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectFont" ng-options="font.fontName for font in fonts"></select>
```

This is the Text Box Which i want to use the selected font

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="Name" ng-style="{'font-family':selectFont.fontName}">
```

When I choose the font vanavil Avvaiyar from drop down. The font gets loaded in the textbox correctly. But not when I choose Bamini. Am I missing Something. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with spaces, can you define a id maybe instead of the name?

Comment: Actually the font with space works correctly. The font "Bamini" is not working

Comment: it's working fine on my end. checked now

Comment: Any reason why its not working for me???

Comment: may be the issue with the CSS. see console whether this font family is applied correctly or any error?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine.. see the snippet below.

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.name = "";
      vm.fonts = [{
          "fontName": "Bamini"
        },
        {
          "fontName": "vanavil Avvaiyar"
        }
      ];
    });

})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Font</label>
      <div class="col-md-2 selectBox">
        <select name="title" class="form-control" ng-options="font.fontName for font in vm.fonts" ng-model="vm.selectFont">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Font</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{vm.selectFont | json}}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.name" ng-style="{'font-family':vm.selectFont.fontName}">
</body>
```

Comment: in your case "vanavil Avvaiyar" is not working. It is a Tamil font.

Comment: It's only about `ng-style` added or not in the attribute. how the font will work is the different thing

Comment: Actually I want the font to work. can you help me do that??

Comment: you have to create fiddle with font style